# Robots.txt in AppEngine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, robots.txt

I have a Java AppEngine web application. I noticed in the dashboard in admin console of appengine that there is a URI error encountered everyday for `/robots.txt`.

How to remove the error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`robots.txt` is a magic URL used by search engine and other robots before processing your site. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) for more details.

The best way of dealing with this error on GAE is to put a robots.txt file, and define it as a static file in your `app.yaml` for gae/python:

```
- url: /(robots\.txt)
  static_files: \1
  upload: (robots\.txt)
```

And in `appengine-web.xml` of gae/java:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0"
                   xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'           xsi:schemaLocation='http://kenai.com/projects/nbappengine/downloads/download/schema/appengine-web.xsd appengine-web.xsd'>
    ....
    <static-files>
        <include path="/favicon.ico" />
        <include path="/robots.txt" />
        <include path="/img/**.png" />
        <include path="/img/**.gif" />
        <include path="/css/**.css" />
</static-files>
```

Of course, you may just as well ignore the errors, they don't matter to anyone but yourself (no human is encountering the error).

Comment: The default generated file I received just contained:   <static-files>
    <include path="**" /> Will the robots.txt file automatically get grabbed then?